# TouchableHighlight in react native not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Hi I have a problem with my `<TouchableHighlight>`. The thing is that the `OnPress` method is not working on android only but on iOS it works fine.

Here is the code with the `TouchableHighlight` :

```
<View>
  {
   this.state.dataVideos.map((item,i) => 
     <TouchableHighlight
       key = {item.contentDetails.videoId}
       onPress = {()=> this.displayVideo(item.contentDetails.videoId)}>
       <View style = {styles.vids}>
          <Image
            source = {{uri: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}}
            style = {{flex: 2, height: '100%', backgroundColor:'#fff', resizeMode:'contain'}}/>
            <Text style = {styles.vidText}>{item.snippet.title}</Text>
       </View>
     </TouchableHighlight>
   )}
</View>
```

EDIT: The `displayVideo` code :

```
  displayVideo(videoId){
      if(this.state.selectedIndex == 0){
        this.setState({
          videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
          showVideo: true
        });
        } else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 1){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        } else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 2){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
          } else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 3){
            this.setState({
              videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
              showVideo: true
            });
        }else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 4){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }
        else if(this.state.selectedIndex ==5 ){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }
        else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 6){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }
        else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 7){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }
        else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 8){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }
        else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 9){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }
        else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 10){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }

        else if(this.state.selectedIndex == 11){
          this.setState({
            videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`,
            showVideo: true
          });
        }

}
```

Comment: why do you want to use specificaly `onPressIn` and not `onPress` ?

Comment: I want to use `OnPress`, I have tried onPressIn but forget to change it again sorry

Comment: try only **<Image />** inside **TouchableHighLight** .

Comment: Do you get any errors or any output?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `displayVideo` ? It might not be an issue with `onPress`, it should work

Comment: Just edited the displayVideo code. And no I'm not getting anything, but on iOS it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

This should work as written, try testing again, maybe with some console logs inside the `displayVideo` method.

That said, you shouldn't be using lambdas in render (`() => ...`) since it's a potential performance issue.

Proper way of doing this would be to return a component. For example `<VideoItem 
 key={item.contentDetails.videoId} onPressCallback={this.displayVideo}/>`

and then you can resolve the id inside component and send it back as a parameter with a callback function.

That way you skip the render lambdas, and also have a clearer and componentized codes for other stuff to come.

Also, there is no need to wrap everyting inside in another `View` try without it, and add styling directly to `TouchableHighlight`.

Comment: I dit not understand how to use the lambdas expression here

Comment: @SauceCurry What part exactly? You shouldn't be using lambas, that's the answer, but instead add component with ID in callback function.